# How to moving UILabels from one UIStackView to another in swift

Tags: swift, uilabel, uistackview

I have 3 horizontal UIStackViews (lets call them labelStackViews) containing a number of UILabels.
All 3 views are inside another horizontal StackView (lets call it mainStackView).

I want to be able to move a label from one labelStackView to another, by dragging it with my finger.

I have used createPanGestureRecognizer to make each label movable.
So if I drag one label within the boundaries of another labelStackView, I want it to switch place.

But I have problems removing and adding a label from one view to the other.

Image of the labels inside each stackview. "-3x", "+2x" is labels in stackview 1, "=" is in stackview 2 and "2", "+3", "+4" is in stackview 3

[image]

This is the code I use, when I have observed that the label is dropped above another labelStackView:

```
lableStackView1.removeArrangedSubview(label1)
labelStackView1.setNeedsLayout()
labelStackView1.layoutIfNeeded()
labelStackView3.addArrangedSubview(label1)
labelStackView3.setNeedsLayout()
```

The result is, that label1 disappears completely from the screen.
And the other labels in labelStackView1 is scaled up to fill the entire labelStackView 1.

I have tried to move those lines of code inside a DispatchQueue.main.async {}.
But it did not helped.

The reason why I have those 3 labelStackViews inside another StackView, is to automatically scale each label and set the labels nicely beside each other.

If it makes a difference, here is the constraints I have on the labelStackViews:

```
labelStackView.axis = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.horizontal
labelStackView.distribution = UIStackView.Distribution.fillProportionally
labelStackView.alignment = UIStackView.Alignment.center
labelStackView.spacing = 5.0
```

and on the UILabels:

```
label.textAlignment = .center
label.layer.masksToBounds = true
label.numberOfLines = 1
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.sizeToFit()
label.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Thank you in advance for any help, I have tried a lot of different things, but I'm a bit new to swift, so maybe I am missing something obvious.

... And here is the full code:

```
import UIKit

class imageViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var upperLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lowerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var screenStackView: UIStackView!

let labelStackView1 = UIStackView()
let labelStackView2 = UIStackView()
let labelStackView3 = UIStackView()

let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
let label3 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
let equalSign = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
var labels: [UILabel] = []

var oldPos: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0), CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0), CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)]
var oldPosInView: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0), CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0), CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)]
var side: [String] = []
var equalPos: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#93DDFA")
    
    labels = [label1, label2, label3]
    
    //Add first stackview to screen and then add labels to stackview
    initStackView(sview: labelStackView1)
    initLabel(label: labels[0], text: "2x", stackView: labelStackView1)
    side.append("Left")
    initLabel(label: labels[1], text: "+3", stackView: labelStackView1)
    side.append("Left")
    
    initStackView(sview: labelStackView2)
    initLabel(label: equalSign, text: "=", stackView: labelStackView2)
    
    initStackView(sview: labelStackView3)
    initLabel(label: labels[2], text: "-4x", stackView: labelStackView3)
    side.append("Right")
    
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    updatePositions(labelsInStackView: labels, stackViewScreen: screenStackView)
    createPanGestureRecognizer(labels: labels)
    
}

func updatePositions(labelsInStackView: [UILabel], stackViewScreen: UIStackView) {
    for (ind, label) in labels.enumerated() {
        oldPos[ind] = getConvertedPoint(label, baseView: view)
        oldPosInView[ind] = label.frame.origin
    }
    equalPos = getConvertedPoint(equalSign, baseView: view)
}

//Create moving gesture for all objects
func createPanGestureRecognizer(labels: [UILabel]) {
    for label in labels {
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(panGesture:)))
        label.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}

//Move the object and deside what to do when the action ends
@objc func handlePanGesture(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // get translation
    let translation = panGesture.translation(in: view)
    panGesture.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), in: view)
    if let myView = panGesture.view {
        myView.center = CGPoint(x: myView.center.x + translation.x, y: myView.center.y + translation.y)
        myView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    //Move objects back to equation when action ends
    if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended) {
        for (ind, label) in labels.enumerated() {
            let newPos = getConvertedPoint(label, baseView: view)
            if (newPos.x != oldPos[ind].x) ||  (newPos.y != oldPos[ind].y) {
                //If the object moved side then change sign and move other objects
                if didLabelMoveSide(ind: ind) {
                    print("It moved side")
                    labelMovedSide(leftStackView: labelStackView1, middleStackView: labelStackView2, rightStackView: labelStackView1, view: view, ind: ind)
                    
                    break
                } else {
                    print("It did not move side")
                    labelNotMovedSide(leftStackView: labelStackView1, middleStackView: labelStackView2, rightStackView: labelStackView3, view: view, ind: ind)
                }
            }
        }
        updatePositions(labelsInStackView: labels, stackViewScreen: screenStackView)
    }
}
}

extension imageViewController {
    func didLabelMoveSide(ind: Int) -> Bool {
        let newP = getConvertedPoint(labels[ind], baseView: view)
        let equalSignPos = equalPos.x
        if (newP.x > equalSignPos &&
            oldPos[ind].x <= equalSignPos) ||
        (newP.x <= equalSignPos && oldPos[ind].x > equalSignPos) {
            return true
        } else {
           return false
        }
    }

func labelNotMovedSide(leftStackView: UIStackView, middleStackView: UIStackView, rightStackView: UIStackView, view: UIView, ind: Int) {
    self.labels[ind].frame.origin = oldPosInView[ind]
    }

func labelMovedSide(leftStackView: UIStackView, middleStackView: UIStackView, rightStackView: UIStackView, view: UIView, ind: Int) {
        //Laben "ind" is moving side
        //Remove it from on view and add it to another
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.side[ind] == "Left" {
            self.labelStackView1.removeArrangedSubview(self.labels[ind])
            self.labelStackView1.setNeedsLayout()
            self.labelStackView1.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.labelStackView3.addArrangedSubview(self.labels[ind])
            self.labelStackView3.setNeedsLayout()
            self.side[ind] = "Right"
        } else {
            self.labelStackView3.removeArrangedSubview(self.labels[ind])
            self.labelStackView3.setNeedsLayout()
            self.labelStackView3.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.labelStackView1.addArrangedSubview(self.labels[ind])
            self.labelStackView1.setNeedsLayout()
            self.side[ind] = "Left"
        }
            
    }
}


func initLabel(label: UILabel, text: String, stackView: UIStackView) {
    label.text = text
    label.font = UIFont(name: "San Francisco", size: 40)
    label.textColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#1C3294")
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: K.textSize)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.layer.masksToBounds = true
    label.frame.size.width = label.intrinsicContentSize.width
    label.frame.size.height = label.intrinsicContentSize.height
    label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    label.layer.borderWidth = 6.0
    label.layer.masksToBounds = true
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.layoutIfNeeded()
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
}

func initStackView(sview: UIStackView) {
    sview.axis = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.horizontal
    sview.distribution = UIStackView.Distribution.fillProportionally
    sview.alignment = UIStackView.Alignment.center
    sview.spacing = 5.0
    screenStackView.addArrangedSubview(sview)
    
}

func getConvertedPoint(_ targetView: UIView, baseView: UIView)->CGPoint{
    var pnt = targetView.frame.origin
    if nil == targetView.superview{
        return pnt
    }
    var superView = targetView.superview
    while superView != baseView{
        pnt = superView!.convert(pnt, to: superView!.superview)
        if nil == superView!.superview{
            break
        }else{
            superView = superView!.superview
        }
    }
    return superView!.convert(pnt, to: baseView)
}

}
```

Comment: Show the code you are currently using to try dragging / moving the labels. Tip: give your labels different background colors to make it easier to see what's what. Also, when you start to drag a label, what exactly do you want to happen? Should the space occupied by that label "collapse" and then empty space "appear" between labels as you are dragging over them? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question and added the full code, so now you can see the code where I can drag labels.
Yes exactly, what you are describing would happen when I moved a label, but I'm not not that far in my project yet.

Answer (score 0):

Because stackViews use auto-layout to arrange and size their subviews, you're going to be fighting an endless battle trying to set frame positions the way you've attempted.

I'm going to suggest a different approach, using only a "container" view and each label as a subview.

On initial layout, we'll use the label frames and a "gap" value to position them, as well as setting the size of the container.

When we "drag and drop" a label, we'll:

- find the position of the drop relative to the other labels
- re-arrange the **array** of labels
- re-layout the labels in their new order

Here is a complete example. It doesn't use any `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections, so you can simply create a new view controller and assign its custom class to `ArrangeLabelsViewController`:

```
class ArrangeLabelsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var parts: [String] = [
        "-3x", "+2x", "=", "2", "+3", "+4",
    ]
    
    // array to hold labels
    var labels: [UILabel] = []
    
    // used in viewDidLayoutSubviews so we don't create infinite recursion
    var labelsCount: Int = 0
    
    // gap between labels
    let labelHGap: CGFloat = 5.0
    
    // gap for top and bottom of labels in container
    let labelVGap: CGFloat = 8.0

    // view to hold the labels
    let containerView = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // very light gray for container background
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        
        parts.forEach { s in
            let v = UILabel()
            v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 30.0)
            v.text = s
            v.backgroundColor = .yellow
            v.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            if s != "=" {
                let pg = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePanGesture(panGesture:)))
                v.addGestureRecognizer(pg)
                v.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            }
            labels.append(v)
            containerView.addSubview(v)
        }
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        // only execute this if number of labels has changed
        if labelsCount != labels.count {
            labelsCount = labels.count
        
            // tell labels to size themselves
            labels.forEach { v in
                v.sizeToFit()
            }
            // get sum of label widths (uses Sequence extension)
            var totalWidth: CGFloat = labels.sum(\.frame.width)
            // add gaps
            totalWidth += CGFloat(labels.count + 1) * labelHGap
            // set container frame size, based on
            //  totalWidth and label height + heightGap
            containerView.frame.size = CGSize(width: totalWidth, height: labels[0].frame.height + labelVGap * 2)
            // center container in view
            containerView.center = view.center
            // on initial layout, we'll "hide" the labels by positioning them
            //  outside the container
            labels.forEach { v in
                v.frame.origin.x = -(v.frame.size.width + 2.0)
                v.center.y = containerView.bounds.midY
            }

            // start with container view clipping to its bounds, so we can
            //  animate the labels into view in their initial positions
            containerView.clipsToBounds = true
            
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        updatePositions()
    }
    
    func updatePositions() -> Void {
        var x: CGFloat = labelHGap
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.labels.forEach { v in
                v.frame.origin.x = x
                v.center.y = self.containerView.bounds.midY
                x += v.frame.width + self.labelHGap
            }
        }, completion: { b in
            // allow labels to be dragged outside the bounds of the container view
            self.containerView.clipsToBounds = false
        })
    }
    
    // just for readability (as opposed to using "left" "right" strings
    enum LeftOrRightSide {
        case left, right
    }
    
    //Move the object and deside what to do when the action ends
    @objc func handlePanGesture(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        
        // unwrap gesture view, its superview,
        // moving label index and equals label index
        guard let movingView = panGesture.view as? UILabel,
              let superV = movingView.superview,
              let mvIDX = labels.firstIndex(of: movingView),
              let equalsIDX = labels.firstIndex(where: { $0.text == "=" })
        else {
            return
        }
        
        let startingSide: LeftOrRightSide = mvIDX < equalsIDX ? .left : .right
        
        // if we're trying to move the only view left of the equals sign
        //  or
        // we're trying to move the only view right of the equals sign
        //  don't allow the move
        if (startingSide == .left && equalsIDX == 1) || (startingSide == .right && equalsIDX == labels.count - 2) {
            return
        }

        // get translation
        let translation = panGesture.translation(in: view)
        panGesture.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), in: view)
        
        // bring the moving view to the front
        superV.bringSubviewToFront(movingView)
        
        // move it
        movingView.center = CGPoint(x: movingView.center.x + translation.x, y: movingView.center.y + translation.y)
        
        // re-position objects when action ends
        if (panGesture.state == .ended) {
            // remove the moving view from the array
            labels.remove(at: mvIDX)
            var newIDX: Int = -1
            // find the first label to the right of where we're dropping
            if let n = labels.firstIndex(where: { $0.center.x > movingView.center.x}) {
                newIDX = n
            } else {
                newIDX = labels.count
            }
            if newIDX == labels.count {
                // we dropped right of the last label
                labels.append(movingView)
            } else {
                // we dropped left of a label
                labels.insert(movingView, at: newIDX)
            }
            let endingSide: LeftOrRightSide = newIDX < equalsIDX ? .left : .right
            if startingSide != endingSide {
                print("Changed Side")
            } else {
                print("Did NOT Change Side")
            }
            updatePositions()
        }
    }

}

// extension to get sum of a property of objects in array
extension Sequence  {
    func sum<T: AdditiveArithmetic>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T) -> T { reduce(.zero) { $0 + predicate($1) } }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted, I have really struggled with UIStackView. I did not know about collection but it is obvious the way to go. Thank you very much!